# Extended Regular Expression in UNIX

Tags: regex, unix, ksh

I don't mean that this question for UNIX only, but I work on Solaris, and I didn't try it on any other OS.
I confused between the extended regular expression:

first:

```
[[ "str" == ?(str|STR) ]] && echo "matched"
```

this work correct, but when:

```
[[ "str str" == ?(str|STR)(.*) ]] && echo "matched"
```

it doesn't work, does it mean that I can only compare one pattern.

Second:

```
[[ "str" =~ ?(str|STR) ]] && echo "matched"
```

I can't use this form here why?, but when:

```
[[ "str" == (str|STR)? ]] && echo "matched"
```

it works correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to combine
[extended globs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)
with
[extended regular expressions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns). I would say this is A Bad Thing.

```
$ set '(str|STR)'

$ [[ 'str' =~ $1 ]] && echo matches
matches

$ [[ 'str str' =~ $1 ]] && echo matches
matches
```